# Problems with CURL on update GLPI

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, server

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit with GLPI version 0.84.8

I am updating GLPI version 0.84.8 > 9.1.4.
I replace the files that the guide tells me and then I access the web.
The update process gives me a CURL error:

[image]

I have CURL installed:

[image]

I have restored the service several times and the server also.

I do not know what to do

Thanks.

Comment: What does `phpinfo();` say about it?

Comment: Do you have multiple PHP-versions installed?

Comment: 'phpinfo();' say : http://imgur.com/7U5oohF @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I have this version of php: http://imgur.com/BpjJpmw

Comment: Seeing cURL listed under _"PHP Credits"_ doesn't mean that it's enabled on your system. That's just generic credits. You should have a separate section for cURL on that page. If not, it's not enabled. Also, check that your web server uses the same PHP version (in the top of the phpinfo()-page) as CLI (the one you showed). They can be set up to use different versions.

Comment: ...and remember to restart the web server after you've installed new PHP-modules.